# Arduino Yun receives UDP packets but prints them with gibberish

Tags: serial, communication, ethernet, arduino-yun

Arduino Yun is set to receive UDP packets. It receives those data with some gibberish.

How is all set up: Arduino Yun (acts as a server) is connected through Ethernet to a PC which is (through WiFi) connected to the router. Another PC (acts as client), is also connected to the router (through Wifi).

Client uses netcat to connect to Arduino Yun. I write something and press enter. The packets are received by the Arduino Yun with some gibberish. For example, I write "test" and press enter, but this is what I receive on the Arduino Yun:
[image]

Sometimes gibberish characters are different, but always exist. This is what Wireshark monitors when I send the "test" packet (with netcat) to my Arduino Yun:
[image]

It shows that indeed I send only "test", so the gibberish is created on the Arduino side, I suppose.

This is my sketch (not the entire code, but the important part):

```
void loop() {
  int udp_received = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (udp_received) {
    char udp_buffer[16];
    udp_buffer[15] = '\0';
    Udp.read(udp_buffer, 15);
    Serial.println(udp_buffer);
  }
}
```

I use BridgeUdp.h
Any insights appreciated.

Comment: udp_received is count of characters received. (and nice progress since previous question)

Comment: `udp_buffer[udp_received ] = '\0';` you send only 5 or 6  characters "test\r\n". the rest is random memory content

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, UDP packets, when printed as strings, might look like gibberish because they are not ASCII but binary in format. You would need to check the documentation and find out what the packet format is or, lacking documentation, you'd need to try and get some idea what the data actually represents.

Comment: Thanks Juraj, I'm moving forward slowly. but steadily. So you say that I read more bytes than I actually receive?

Comment: @S.Imp, if you send "test", you receive "test"

Comment: you don't read more. the function fills only so much bytes as received. the rest of the buffer is uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Juraj if you look at his [wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEc3Y.jpg), you'll see that the UDP packet received is 47 bytes. "test" is probably only four bytes. So he's got another 43 bytes to figure out.

Comment: @S.Imp, it is the envelope

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a small packet of about 5 or 6 characters (depending on your line ending). That is being received into a 16 byte buffer which has contents unknown.  So the first 5 or 6 bytes of the array have valid data in it. The rest is whatever was already in there.

You need to use the return value of `Udp.parsePacket()` to tell you how many of the bytes in your buffer are actually valid received bytes and only print those.

The simplest way:

```
Serial.write(udp_buffer, udp_received);
```

Comment: int udp_received = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (udp_received) {
    char udp_buffer[udp_received];
    Udp.read(udp_buffer, udp_received);
    Serial.write(udp_buffer, udp_received); Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sounds about right

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. It prints only the first character of each line. For example if I send "test", ENTER, "test", ENTER", "hello", ENTER, Serial monitor prints "tth"

Comment: Maybe it's the return value from Udp.read() actually. I haven't used the Yun for UDP before...

Comment: And the packetSize is always printed as 1, that's weird

Answer (score 1):

You send only 5 or 6 characters "test\r\n". the rest is random memory content.

The return value of [parsePacket](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPParsePacket) should be the count of received characters, but [the implementation in BridgeUdp](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Bridge/blob/c185c2f2803a8b869b2b3d931e97a8000e55dbac/src/BridgeUdp.cpp#L105) is wrong and returns always 1 on success.

You you can use `BridgeUdp.available()` to get the count.

```cpp
void loop() {
  if (Udp.parsePacket()) {
    int udp_received = Udp.available();
    char udp_buffer[16];
    Udp.read(udp_buffer, udp_received);
    udp_buffer[udp_received] = '\0';
    Serial.println(udp_buffer);
  }
}
```